# Acitivity ignores showing Toasts when executed from my Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, toast

Why do I only see the "first" toast and not the others (should be) created from my thread?

```
public class BannerExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "first toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        new MyThread(this).start();

    }

    class MyThread extends Thread {

        private Context context;

        public MyThread(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void run() {

            Looper.prepare(); // An exception told me to add this - i have no clue why

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, i + "whoho", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not be calling `Looper.prepare`. You were getting the exception because you were doing something wrong:
2. Toasts are part of the UI toolkit, and therefore must be accessed from the UI thread - this is why you were getting an exception
3. I suggest you swap `Thread` for [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and make use of the `onProgressUpdate` method to create your toasts as this automatically runs on the UI thread. Otherwise you'll need to use a handler.
4. Pass the context from `getBaseContext` rather than the context from the current activity to your constructor